# Using pandas in python to pull a specific string from a column

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a CSV file which contains the columns as follows:

`"Date","Time","TimeZone","Name","Type","Status","Currency","Gross","Fee","Net","From Email Address","To Email Address","Transaction ID","Shipping Address","Address Status","Item Title","Item ID","Shipping and Handling Amount","Insurance Amount","Sales Tax","Option 1 Name","Option 1 Value","Option 2 Name","Option 2 Value","Reference Txn ID","Invoice Number","Custom Number","Quantity","Receipt ID","Balance","Address Line 1","Address Line 2/District/Neighborhood","Town/City","State/Province/Region/County/Territory/Prefecture/Republic","Zip/Postal Code","Country","Contact Phone Number","Subject","Note","Country Code","Balance Impact"`

I am trying to just grab the rows of data that contain the string **Chain × Jewelry × Necklace** in the **Item Title** column.

The name under each item title is different. For example. One might be **Chain × Jewelry × Necklace Popcorn Necklace** others are BLANK VALUES but I just want all of them that contain **Chain × Jewelry × Necklace**

How can I use pandas to pull these specific rows containing this string? I am having trouble. Any help is greatly appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('path/to/your/file.csv')
df = df[df['Item Title'].fillna('').str.contains('Chain × Jewelry × Necklace') & df['Name'].fillna('').str.len().gt(0)]
```

Comment: Perhaps I should've mentioned this earlier but a few of the rows have a blank value. Therefore, when I use this I get the error **"ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values"**

Comment: @Crunchy check my answer now :)

Comment: that worked great! Thank you so much I appreciate you. Lastly, if there anyway I can remove rows that have blank data in the "Name" column? Like if no name exists just remove the row? Your awesome for the help!!!!

Comment: @Crunchy check the update. I added a condition so now it only selects rows that have `Chain × Jewelry × Necklace` in the `Item Title` column, and where the value of the `Name` row that row is not empty.

Comment: I fixed the empty cell issue under "Names" by adding ``df.dropna(subset = ["Name"], inplace=True)``. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Just saw your update. That actually works really well too. Wow you have helped me so much and saved me a lot of time. THANK YOU!!!!!

Comment: Thanks, I accepted your answer. May I ask one last question. I was using ``(df.apply(lambda s: s.eq('CA').any(), axis=1))]`` to filter out anything including CA. But now I do not want this data. Is there a way I can drop anything containing CA? Specifically I am trying to drop anything in the **Shipping Address** column that contains "CA" .

Comment: Sure, you can just add a line like this: `df = df[df['Shipping Address'] != 'CA']`. That'll select all rows where `Shipping Address` is not `CA`.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you're going to add that to other conditions with `&` (like I did in my answer), you'll need to either wrap it in parentheses, e.g. `df[... & (df['Shipping Address']) != 'CA']`, OR, use `.ne()` instead of `!=`: `df[... & df['Shipping Address'].ne('CA')]`. I prefer the latter, but that's just a matter of opinion :)

Comment: Perfect! I changed your idea a bit and did ``res = df[df["Shipping Address"].str.contains("CA") == False]`` and that worked flawlessly. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction. I am overjoyed by your help today. Seriously, big gold star for you :)))))!

Comment: Lol, thank you! Accepting and upvoting are they way to go in terms of thank on SO - it gives me more points! :) I'm glad to help you! _Really_ glad :)

Comment: I understand. I accepted but sadly dont have enough reputation to vote yet. When I get enough ill come back and vote up your reply. Much love <3

Comment: @Crunchy look like you've asked a question and got [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70795247/17242583) that worked for you. If you accept that answer, you'll also get enough rep to vote... ;)

Comment: Your right. Just accepted that answer and got enough rep. I voted up your replies. I cannot thank you enough for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```
df[df["Item Title"].str.contains(r"^(?=.*\bChain\b)(?=.*\bJewelry\b)(?=.*\bNecklace\b).+", regex=True)]
```

Comment: I forgot to mention but some of the rows contain blank values in the **"Item Title"** column. I tried adding **na = 0** to this and still get an error **"KeyError: "None of [Index([False,  True,  True,  True,     0,     0, False, False,     0,  True,\n       ...\n           0,     0,     0,  True,  True,  True,     0,     0,     0,     0],\n      dtype='object', length=2028)] are in the [columns]"**. The code I used was ``res = df[df["Item Title"].str.contains(r"^(?=.*\bChain\b)(?=.*\bJewelry\b)(?=.*\bNecklace\b).+", na = 0,regex=True)]
res.to_csv('output.csv')``

Comment: The above answer worked. However, thank you for taking your time to comment I appreciate it!

Comment: @Crunchy add `na=False` instead.